# Installing Ubuntu to try to resolve a problem

Tags: windows-7

I have a Lenovo L430. Mousepad and trackpoint don't work in W7. I was advised to try Ubuntu to see if the problem is in software or hardware. I have no experience with Ubuntu. 
Can I do a "dry run" or partial installation to see how does Ubuntu work without actually installing it? If yes, how? 
Will I be able to restore W7 after I try Ubuntu? How? 
Am I in danger of losing user files?

All advice is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: You can [Try Ubuntu before you install it](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/try-ubuntu-before-you-install).

Comment: As an aside, you are in danger of losing user files *always*, even if you do not change or try other OSs, or even if you do not switch your computer on. Disks **do** die. Just having to ask the question is a clear symptom of a problem. Do yourself a favor and have a backup.

Comment: Thank you. I do have a backup. Perhaps I phrased my question in the wrong way. I was curious if the installation itself causes to loose user files.

Answer (score 3):

You can actually try ubuntu without actually installing it, but you need a USB flash drive withat least 1GB of space to have it on. [Here is a good tutorial on how to set it up](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows).

After you have a LiveUSB created you just reboot the computer with the flash drive still connected. you might have to go into BIOS and give boot priority to the flash drive. Then your computer will boot into ubuntu, which you can then use to play around with.

Comment: Thank you. I have created a DVD for installing Ubuntu. Is there a reason why I should use a flash drive instead?

Comment: Well if you use a flash drive not only would the loading be much faster (depending on the flash drive) but you could also allocate some space to hold changed files for settings, installed apps and such. Pretty much like a mini OS running off of your flash drive.